# using widget or hardcoding in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

My client has given me an outline of the wordpress theme he wants. I have begun the process. but since this is my first order in wordpresss theme development, I need some guides from lads here.

My client has told me to place a newsletter form on the right sidebar. As a theme developer, shall I ask him what plugin or widget he use for newsletter? Or I simply should write direct html markup for form/input/submit.

There is another similar feature. Below the newsletter box, I should place a similar form (an input for the visitor to enter a code and get a file);

Please help me. Thanks...

Comment: Take the time to learn WordPress plugin development. It should only take an hour or two to build a working understanding of wp plugins and only a day or two to get into the full swing of it (if you known php5). This will be more desirable to the client (more return business/referrals) and will look better on a resume/profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask for Plugin for both of the sections.
If you suggest to the client, after search on the wordpress.org, then will be plus.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to be a widget since you can make it work with any newsletter provider giving that to the client to input, than to hardcode it... have you advised Mailchimp to your client?
It has a lot of functional and editable widgets for Wordpress

Comment: thanks. it already has a running site. I got the idea on how to make it work. thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

1. For the newsletter subscription I would suggest http://blog.mailchimp.com/wordpress-plugins-for-mailchimp/. This plugin is very effective and can be directly incorporate with the customer's mailchimp account. So in the future he can send bulk emails using the mailchimp list.

   Or else you can use this plugin too: http://wordpress.org/plugins/newsletter-sign-up/
2. For the second form you can simply create a widget with the input box and submit button and redirect to a page to download the file. Create a page template in wordpress with the download functionality and assign it to a page.